# How do I put hyperlink in buttons with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Can someone help me please,
I have a view dashboard and I want to put a hyperlink button in HTML, using a Laravel 5 command. When that button is clicked, it may show encomendas view.

This is the view Dashboard:

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('zoekenindex') }}" class="btn btn-default">Left</a>
```

In my controller I have this:

```
Route::get('zoekenindex', array('as' => 'zoekenindex', 'uses' => 'encomendas@show'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood the question, but try this:

```
<a href="{{ action('EncomendasController@show') }}">Left</a>
```

`EncomendasController` is the name of the controller.
`show` is the method inside the controller.

And remember to define it in routes.php.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think I understood your problem quite well. But, I think that what you're trying to do is to list all "Encomendas" and provide links to each one. Is that right?